# Using WITH Statement in SAP HANA table functions

Tags: hana

Is it possible to use the WITH statement in SAP HANA table functions or is there any alternative that I can use within table functions?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "MY_SCHEMA"."TF_TEST_1" ()
RETURNS TABLE ( 
mytext NVARCHAR(200)

) LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT SQL SECURITY INVOKER AS
BEGIN RETURN

WITH X AS (SELECT 'asdf' AS mytext FROM dummy)
SELECT * FROM X;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table function you need to explicitly return a table with `return` statement.
As experiment showed, `with` is not allowed inside `return` (similar to CTAS: create table from `select` statement starting with `with` throws an error).

But you can assign the result of your statement to [table variable](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.04/en-US/ea5065d06d14426799d879234d8e3e7b.html) and return it.

```
create function test_tf (x int)
returns table (
  id int
)
as begin

  res = with a as (
    select x as id
    from dummy
  )
  select *
  from a;

  return(:res);
end;

select *
from test_tf(1);


|   | ID|
|--:|--:|
|  1|  1|
```

But in HANA SQLScript we prefer to use table variables instead ow `with` statements, because they allow step-by-step debugging of the code with no need to rewrite it or run externally as SQL statement with prepared input and `select` placed after each `with`. You can declare them on-the-fly, that allows you not to declare something strange upfront. So the way to rewrite it is:

```
alter function test_tf (x int)
returns table (
  id int
)
as begin

  /*with a as */
  a =
    select x as id
    from dummy
  ;
  
  res = 
    select *
    from :a;

  return(:res);
end;
```

Note: the only thing is to add a colon before table variable when you access it so parser can distinguish it from table name.

If you want to debug your code before publishing as a function, just replace `create function` statement with [`do`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/52103853351841f6a1e87f40b2686da9.html) and `return` with `select * from <return variable>`. To view intermediary results you still need to place `select * from :table_var` somewhere inbetween, because as far as I know anonymous block doesn't allow debuggind with debugger.

```
do (in x int => ?)
begin

  /*with a as */
  a =
    select x as id
    from dummy
  ;
  
  res = 
    select *
    from :a;

  select * from :res;
  --return(:res);
end;
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Is the query optimizer rearranging the query from variable a with the query from res? Or will the query assigned to a always be executed independently? (I am actually also not sure about what behaviour I expact for the WITH statement?)

Comment: @JonasM. The query is executed as a single statements. I've tried to show more details, but it was not so easy to reproduce. What is going on behind the scene: on some day I've monitored currently ececuting queries in the Performance tab and found that my long running procedure actually executes a single statement, where each table variable is placed as `with` statement. It looked like `with var_<some_generated_name> as (/*Table variable <table variable name>*/` with this autogenerated comment (or something similar). So the query is the same as with `with`

Comment: That's incorrect. When possible/sensible, the HANA query optimiser will **inline** table variables into statements that refer to those table variables. 
There can be cases, where this is not generally possible/sensible - but as a rule of thumb assume that inlining will occur.